# Build.Gradle Error (22,0) Could not find method chandroid()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am new in Android Studio, I'm already completed my simple app. But the problem is I have Gradle problem when try to open the project after copy the app folder from my desktop to my laptop.
(including screenshot link for better understanding of the problem)

**main Build.Gradle**
http://puu.sh/vQl8c/bcade1a2e2.png

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

// It won't required
//    chandroid {
//        compileSdkVersion 19
//    }

**app Build.Grade**
http://puu.sh/vQl9v/e7363ddb74.png

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.afinal.eaglearms.learnk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chandroid {
   compileSdkVersion 19
}
```

Remove this from your main/root `build.gradle` file. It should be android instead of chandroid, that is also not required because you already defined in `build.gradle` of app module.